# ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" is not working in Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I've been running into some performance issues in a Windows Phone 7.5 application I'm working on. I have a `ListBox` that is using `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` and a `DataTemplate`. It seems to work fine except for poor performance. While doing some performance profiling I'm seeing, while I scroll the list as much as 62% of the CPU is being used creating a new instance of a custom User Control I have placed in the `DataTemplate`. I understood the whole point of `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` was to re-use all the `UIElements` in the `ListBox` and not need to create new instances or dispose old ones so I would expect this is exactly the kind of thing that should not be happening.

Here's the relevant XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EpisodeRows}" toolkit:TiltEffect.SuppressTilt="True" Margin="12,0" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="111" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding TilesVisibility}">
                    <landerGame:LevelTileUserControl PartText="{Binding PartText_1}" ScoreText="{Binding ScoreText_1}" Star1Visibility="{Binding Star1Vi
                    <landerGame:LevelTileUserControl PartText="{Binding PartText_2}" ScoreText="{Binding ScoreText_2}" Star1Visibility="{Binding Star1Vi
                    <landerGame:LevelTileUserControl PartText="{Binding PartText_3}" ScoreText="{Binding ScoreText_3}" Star1Visibility="{Binding Star1Vi
                    <landerGame:LevelTileUserControl PartText="{Binding PartText_4}" ScoreText="{Binding ScoreText_4}" Star1Visibility="{Binding Star1Vi
                    <landerGame:LevelTileUserControl PartText="{Binding PartText_5}" ScoreText="{Binding ScoreText_5}" Star1Visibility="{Binding Star1Vi
                    <landerGame:LevelTileUserControl PartText="{Binding PartText_6}" ScoreText="{Binding ScoreText_6}" Star1Visibility="{Binding Star1Vi
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding EpisodeTitleText}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,5" 
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here's a screenshot of my performance profiling results while scrolling there list:
[image: Performance Profiling Results]

Here's what the list looks like (It's a level select for a game):
[image: Level Select]

I've looked around and kind find any articles addressing `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` not appearing to work. Any insights would be most appreciated at this point.

**EDIT:** I've uploaded a the full relevant code for this project is anyone cares to try it for themselves here: http://maketag.net/landerGame.rar

Comment: I forget for the phone, but do you have to declare VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" maybe?

Comment: @ChrisW. I gave it a go, but `IsVirtualizing` isn't settable in WP7 XAML =(.

Comment: Oh I think I see your issue, ditch the virtualizing on your nested grid, keep it on the listbox itself. Then set a fixed height value on your listbox. If you don't the rendering engine just thinks it has infinite space and wont actually invoke virtualization to begin with. Which is something I just learned recently myself the hard way lol. Then you should be good, give it a shot.

Comment: @ChrisW I gave it a go but no joy =(. Still getting the exact same slow performance and very large amount of CPU time being spent initialising new LevelTileUserControl instances while scrolling. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Just wondering why you are using a ListBox here? Seems there are better layout options that would give you better performance.

Comment: @Bryant I'm all ears. I should probably be using ItemControl at least but I haven't gotten around to it yet, and I expect the performance increase would be relatively insignificant. WrapPanel would be an option but I need to be able to have headers every now and again and I'm unsure if that's possible with WrapPanel? I originally had a nested Virtualised ListBox, which was performing slow (probably no slower than it is now..) and I found my custom UserControls were being completely recreated while scrolling and I thought removing the nest might solve the problem. Didn't seem to help though.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to test since you haven't provided any information about your user controls.

I'd suggest moving away from a `ListBox` since the behavior you are trying to emulate here is really a [WrapPanel](http://phone.codeplex.com/).

Because of the way you add so many user controls to each `ListBox` item, I'm guessing it is causing a performance hit. If you switched to a `WrapPanel` and then bound to your collection of items, you would probably get better performance since each item would be virtualized versus having to try to virtualize six items at a time (which probably isn't working).

**Edit:** Looking through your code I think there are a few changes you could make to improve performance. First off, get rid of the `ListBox` and use an `ItemsControl` like this:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="LANDER GAME">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <controls:PivotItem Header="Episodes">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EpisodeRows}" toolkit:TiltEffect.SuppressTilt="True" Margin="12,0">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="111" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding TilesVisibility}">
                                ...
                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding EpisodeTitleText}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,5" Visibility="{Binding TitleVisibility}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </controls:PivotItem>
```

The thing I would do would be to get rid of the hard coded `PartText_1`, `PartText_2` type of variables. Just create a list of items and have another `ItemsControl` inside your other items control.

Just getting rid of the `ListBox` made it much smoother. I also removed the `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` since it caused a performance hit at the start, once it loaded it seemed smoother.

Comment: The custom UserControl is simplicity itself. It just exposes the properties on some simple properties of text boxes allowing them to be databindable in the DataTemplate. There's nothing going on programmatically inside them. I could have just copied the XAML inside them into the DataTemplate 6 times, but that seemed like a bad idea. Is it possible to have intermittent headers in a wrap panel? I'd be willing to give it a shot if that could work. I'm still perplexed why my custom UserControl won't get properly recycled at all.

Comment: Any chance you could create a simple example from your code that has the same performance issue? If you post that then it would be pretty easy to troubleshoot it.

Comment: I've uploaded a stripped down version of the entire solution here: [link](http://maketag.net/landerGame.rar). I see the performance problems on my Omnia 7 and less noticeably, but still really bad, on the wp7.5 emulator (core duo 2.7ght). My main concern is the massive amount of CPU time spend completely recreating all my custom UserControls as I scroll which seems like a horrible waste. Though anything that would speed up the scrolling fast enough would of course be fantastic. If I can't figure this out I'll just have to simplify the list and use far simpler UI elements on each row.

Comment: Testing it out. It seems like you get better performance if you turn the recycling off since it isn't constantly creating new instances of your user control. Going to test out one other thing.

Comment: @Byrant. I was away without internet on the weekend so couldn't reply sooner. Putting `ItemsControl` inside a ``ScollViewer` will actually break any kind of virtualisation from happening as the `ItemsControl` will end up being the full height of the list and think it's being rendered in its entirety. I did use some code from [here](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-7-itemscontrol) to get `ItemsControl` working though, but it does not improve performance and I get the same recreation of my user controls while scrolling. Turning off `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` **cont..**

Comment: does not appear to affect anything. The only thing that seemed to improve scrolling is turning off virtualisation altogether, which I feel is too much of a memory burden but I may just try it all the same. It's a real headscratcher... basically `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` is not working at all the way I understand it's meant to. Thanks for looking into this btw!